# Google AI Vision / Image labeling?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence

i try to label images with the Google Vision API - and this code works fine generally:

```
from google.cloud import vision
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
  path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
  credsFN = os.path.join(path, "creds.json")
  os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credsFN

  imageURL = "https://www.24mantra.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/banner-3.jpg"

  client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
  image = vision.Image()
  image.source.image_uri = imageURL
  features = [vision.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION]
  features = [vision.Feature(type_=feature_type) for feature_type in features]
  requ = vision.AnnotateImageRequest(image=image, features=features)
  resp = client.annotate_image(request=requ)
  for label in resp.label_annotations:
    print(f"{label.score:4.0%}: {label.description}")
```

Now i tried it with some other url like:

https://www.juicer.io/api/posts/459631754/images.jpg?external_id=CiE264cqZcw&s=199f57b090efba5ef332c3ff09d7b14554f84bfc

(when you click the link you will see that the image opens without problems in the browser)

But when i run the above program with this link it is not working anymore and i get an empty response?
How can i get also results from Google Vison API with this links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link with an error is having an **error code: 7** with an **error message:** `"We're not allowed to access the URL on your behalf. Please download the content and pass it in."`

The possible workaround for this is to **store** your image in **Google Cloud Storage(GCS)** and use the `gs://uri` instead. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels#detect_labels_in_a_remote_image) for your reference.